# Activiti: how to stop the process

Tags: activiti, bpmn

***What I want:***

***I want to stop Activiti process***. For example, I need to restart my server, so I want to stop all activities and then start them again.

***What I do:***

Suspend all active activities with the code below:

```
for (ProcessInstance processInstance : runtumeService.createProcessInstanceQuery().active().list)
  runtimeService.suspendProcessInstanceById(processInstance.getProcessInstanceId())
```

***What the problems:***

I have two problems:

1. ***Suspend doesn't work for tasks in an active state.*** Moreover, seems that it isn't work even if process hasn't any task in a active state.
2. ***ActivitiOptimisticLockingException.*** It is thrown each time I suspend the process when it has active (in progress) service task.

***What a question:***

How to resolve the problems above

***P.S.***

To clearify an issue I can provide you more details, more code examples or even a very simple demo  which illustrate the problem. If something isn't clear enough - ask, you are welcome!

Comment: You want to start all stopped process again, is that right?

Comment: It's also right, but at the moment I can't even suspend all my processes correctly